# Overriding RequestEventListenerAdapter methods on Spring Boot (Stormpath)

Tags: spring-boot, stormpath

I've been trying to override Stormpath's [RequestEventListenerAdapter](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/events.html) methods to populate an account's [Custom Data](https://stormpath.com/blog/custom-data-search-powerful-identity-management-java) when the user logs in or creates an account.

I created a class that extends `RequestEventListenerAdapter` and am trying to override the on `SuccessfulAuthenticationRequestEvent` and the on `LogoutRequestEvent` to make some simple outputs to the console to test if they are working (A simple "Hello world!" for example). But when I do any of these actions on the application, none of these events are triggering. So I was wondering if anyone here could help me out, I'm not sure if the bean I'm supposed to declare is in the right place or if I'm missing some kind of configuration for the events to trigger. Thanks for any help and let me know if more information is needed.

This is my custom class:

```
import com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.authc.LogoutRequestEvent;
import com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.authc.SuccessfulAuthenticationRequestEvent;
import com.stormpath.sdk.servlet.event.RequestEventListenerAdapter;

public class CustomRequestEventListener extends RequestEventListenerAdapter {

@Override
public void on(SuccessfulAuthenticationRequestEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Received successful authentication request event: {}\n" + e);
}

@Override
public void on(LogoutRequestEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Received logout request event: {}\n" + e);
}
}
```

This is the bean that I'm not sure where to place:

```
@Bean
public RequestEventListener stormpathRequestEventListener() {
    return new CustomRequestEventListener();
}
```

Comment: You should be able to put the `@Bean` in any class marked with `@Configuration`. Even the main Spring Boot class that's annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Yes I currently have the `@Bean` in the main class (`@SpringBootApplication`), just wasn't sure if it was supposed to go somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing looks exactly right. I have created [a sample project](https://github.com/mrioan/spring-boot-webmvc-custom-listener) demonstrating how to get things working. You could take a look at it (it is very simple) and compare it with what you have.

I also added instructions on how to get it running so you can see that it does indeed work.

Comment: Awesome! I'll check it out and get back to you.

Comment: Yeah everything on my side seems to be the same but still no output from the Event Listener, is it because I'm using Social Loin instead of the regular login? I'm also trying with a logout event and it isn't working either :/

Comment: In the example I provided I tried with both Facebook and Google and the events where properly received. Is it possible for you to share the relevant parts of the project? If so then you can create a ticket to us here https://support.stormpath.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Alright, I'll submit a ticket because I no longer no what I must be doing wrong, thank you very much for your help!